# binary search for list in python

Tags: python, binary-search

My code for binary search function in a list returns true for a value in the list, but returns None (instead of false) for values not in the list.

Can someone please explain me what I'm doing wrong?

The program is:

```
def searchlist(x,alist):
        end=int(len(alist)-1)
        mid=int(len(alist)/2)

        while len(alist)>2:
                if  x==alist[mid] or x==alist[0] or x==alist[end] :
                        return("true")
                        break
                elif x>alist[mid]:
                        alist=alist[mid:]
                        mid=int(len(alist)/2)
                        end=int(len(alist)-1)


                elif x<alist[mid]:
                        alist=alist[:mid]
                        mid=int(len(alist)/2)
                        end=int(len(alist)-1)

                else:
                        return("false")

aList=[2,3,5,7,9,12,14,23,34,45,67,89,101]

xnum=int(input("enter a number:"))
searchlist(xnum,aList)
print(searchlist(xnum,aList))
```

Comment: Without diving into the code, `alist` is going down to 2 values and it's ending the `while` loop, causing it to return `None`. I'd suggest print out the current state of the list each loop, and manually run through your code to figure at what point it's not working as expected. Edit: Actually, it looks like your `else` statement won't ever execute. Put `return False` after the while loop instead and it should work (I'd suggest use `True` and `False` instead of strings).

Comment: If you want to return false if you don't find what you want in your list you should put the return false after the loop, not in the loop

Comment: your second `elif` perfomed. If you delete this block, then return `('false')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `None` when your function does not return a value. This happens because the while loop terminates without going into the "else" branch. 
A better practice would be to return True (not the string, but the Boolean value) when you find the value in the list, and return False after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop cannot catch the else statement. you don't need that else. try this :

```
def searchlist(x,alist):
    end=int(len(alist)-1)
    mid=int(len(alist)/2)
    result = False
    while len(alist)>2:
            if  x==alist[mid] or x==alist[0] or x==alist[end] :
                    result = True
            elif x>alist[mid]:
                    alist=alist[mid:]
                    mid=int(len(alist)/2)
                    end=int(len(alist)-1)

            elif x<alist[mid]:
                    alist=alist[:mid]
                    mid=int(len(alist)/2)
                    end=int(len(alist)-1)

    return result

aList=[2,3,5,7,5,67,89,101]

xnum=int(input("enter a number:"))
print(searchlist(xnum,aList))
```